# Parse.com manifest exception with ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am building an app with parse push notifications service. I am using my custom receiver which is declared in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.appname.push.PushReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When I build and test the app for the 1st time, it works. But when I make any change, build the app and run it (the previous version should be reinstalled), I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
    (Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
    at android.app.Activityappname.performLaunchActivity(Activityappname.java:2416)
    at android.app.Activityappname.handleLaunchActivity(Activityappname.java:2476)
    at android.app.Activityappname.-wrap11(Activityappname.java)
    at android.app.Activityappname$H.handleMessage(Activityappname.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.Activityappname.main(Activityappname.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
    (Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
    at com.parse.ParsePush.checkForManifestAndThrowExceptionIfNeeded(ParsePush.java:152)
    at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:78)
    at com.company.appname.api.AppnameApi.subscribeToParseChannels(AppnameApi.java:1034)
    at com.company.appname.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:140)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
    ... 9 more
```

I need to uninstall the app manually and install a fresh copy every time I make any change.

Do somebody know what can be wrong? Thank you.

The version of Parse.com library is 1.8.1.

Comment: Your receiver name in the manifest and the class name show be the same

Comment: I am using my own class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. And this receiver class is in manifest. As I said, the app is working when it is build and run on a device without previous version. When I just make any change, build it and run from Android Studio, I will get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back i got mail from parse.com saying that "Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on January 28, 2017" so please check that you are getting exception because of this or is there any other reason because even i am not sure.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I know about this. But this is not causing the exception. I was getting this IllegalStateException in november 2015 when I was also making some changes in the app. And in this time it was not announced.